X11 authentication issue while running GUI in a container on a remote server
Problem:
I need to run an application with a GUI in a docker container. The container must run on a remote server which I can access using ssh though a Jump Host. I'm doing the following operations:

From my local machine I connect to the jump host: ssh -X -C jump-user@jump-host

From the jump-host I connect to the remote server: ssh -X -C remote-user@remote-host

On the remote server I run a docker container with the following line:
docker run --restart always --network host --env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix my-container:latest


The application doesn't start and I get the following message:
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Is there a way to solve this problem?
Setup

The remote machine is headless and I can only login using ssh.
When I connect to the remote-host both xeyes and firefox (if I export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority) work.
The DISPLAY env variable exists and is set.

Issues
If I'm trying to run xhost + I get the following error message:
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host

xhost:  must be on local machine to enable or disable access control.

and the problem is still there.
